# Openfire admin port and HTTP binding port

Tags: openfire

I just install installed openfire and webchat plugin.The webchat plugin working fine in HTTP binding port of openfire. Can i set same port for both admin  and HTTP binding ?

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible,

because admin console and HTTP-binding both are totally different services of openfire.
So if you will try to set same port for both , it might throw error like 'port already in use'.